# Is this Netty UDP model really multithreaded?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, netty

I developed a client/server application that is receiving an initial connect at TCP port 10000 and after negotiating, the server generates a game room by Binding an UDP socket to a another port (like 10001) and client that connects to this Room, should connnect using UDP to this port.

This is the code I run to create every game Room:

```
...
EventLoopGroup udpBossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
Bootstrap bUdp = new Bootstrap();
bUdp.group(udpBossGroup);
bUdp.handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
bUdp.handler(new UDPInitializer());
bUdp.channel(NioDatagramChannel.class);
bUdp.bind(udpPortCounter).sync();
...
```

I tried checking on netstat but it shows the same process ID, maybe it's the father process ID:

```
netstat -lanp
udp6       0      0 :::10024                :::*                              26568/java
udp6       0      0 :::10025                :::*                                26568/java
udp6       0      0 :::10026                :::*                                26568/java
```

PS shows me same PID but different LWP, so I believe they are using different threads:

```
ps -eLF | grep -i java
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     26568  4088 26568  0   26 620767 66144  0 10:16 pts/2    00:00:00 java -jar gameserver.jar
root     26568  4088 26569  0   26 620767 66144  0 10:16 pts/2    00:00:00 java -jar gameserver.jar
root     26568  4088 26570  0   26 620767 66144  1 10:16 pts/2    00:00:00 java -jar gameserver.jar
root     26568  4088 26571  0   26 620767 66144  0 10:16 pts/2    00:00:00 java -jar gameserver.jar
```

Question are:
Is this mode really multithreaded on the UDP sockets (Every socket runs on a different thread)?

How can I make sure it's using a different thread on every UDP socket?

Answer (score 0):

1. Print thread ID using `Thread.currentThread().getId()` to confirm is using multithread on server when you write a multithread client(or multil clients) to send data incessantly.
2. I found you used only one NioEventLoopGroup(1), that means only one thread work for connect, receive data etc. , if only one THREAD ID print on STEP 1,  try this:

   `EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
   EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
   b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)`
3. Netty process task using thread pool (NioDatagramChannel), so threads reusable to process different socket data,  "How can I make sure it's using a different thread on every UDP socket?" I don't suggest do this because it will cost a lot of threads when lots of clients connect your server, you should keep data thread safe on another way.

Comment: I printed getId(), it shows a different ID on every connection: Thread: 34, then: Thread: 36. Can I say then it IS running on a different thread? Thanks

Comment: Yous should confirm your print is same game room?  I suggest you use 2 event group as above